# how to convert YYYYMMDD to MJD format using bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

How to convert javascript equivalent of algorithm to convert YYYYMMDD to MJD modified julan day to bash script here is the javascript code

```
function YMDtoMJD (year, month, day)
{    

var year;
var monthi
var day;
var yr  = Math.floor (year); 
var mn  = Math.floor (month);
var day = Math.floor (day);          
var hr  = 0.0;                    // Hours are not valid
var L;
var julian;    
var mjd;


// In leap years, -1 for Jan, Feb, else 0
L = Math.ceil ((mn - 14) / 12);

var p1 = day - 32075 + Math.floor (1461 * (yr + 4800 + L) / 4);    
var p2 = Math.floor (367 * (mn - 2 - L * 12) / 12);
var p3 = 3 * Math.floor (Math.floor ((yr + 4900 + L) / 100) / 4);
julian = p1 + p2 - p3;        
julian = julian + (hr / 24.0) - 0.5;

mjd = julian - 2400000.5; 
return (mjd);
}
```

I tried in bash script but stuck in middle

```
#!/bin/bash
#clear

mn=12
Yr=2014
Dd=23

L=`ceil $((($mn-14)/12))`

p1=$(($Dd-32075+`floor $(((1461*(($Yr+4800+$L)/4))))`))
```

Please help me to convert it to bash
below is my floor and ceil function i am using

```
   floor_val=
    function floor() {
      float_in=$1
      floor_val=${float_in/.*}
   }
  float_val=$1
floor $float_val
echo $floor_val

ceil_val=
function ceiling() {
float_in=$1
ceil_val=${float_in/.*}
ceil_val=$((ceil_val+1))
}

float_val=$1
ceiling $float_val
echo $ceil_val
```

Comment: There's no `floor` command in `bash`.

Comment: But you don't need it, because `bash` arithmetic is integer-only. Division always returns the floor.

Answer (score 0):

For ceil(a,b) function you can use the formula *ceil=1+floor((a-1)/b)*

```
function ceil() { echo $((1+(($1-1)/$2))); }
```

If you have *bc*, you can use that too.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
DAY="20200101"
MJD=$(( ( $(date +%s -d "$DAY") / 86400 ) + 40588 ))
#echo $MJD
58849
```

Comment: testing... found the offset value to be 40487.
Reasoning: your day might be some local date and thus has a time zone related shift.
instead a value of DAY="2020-01-01 UTC" will lead to a platform independent result. the date command will /script-internally/ return a value of 1577836800 (that you can check with any epoch-decoder even online, e.g. this one with 24h outputs: https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php ). finally you will see your value of 58849 - when using an offset of 40587.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of doing the math yourself, I think that the easiest way to achieve the task would be to use the `date` command. You can specify the date and time you want it to display (instead of the current date and time which it would use by default) via the `--date` option. Fortunately, `date` is smart enough to recognize a couple of formats (including the one you have) correctly by default. Then you use the `+FORMAT` syntax to specify the format in which you would like the date and time to be output.

For example:

```
$ date --date='20160921' +'%m%y%d'
091621
```

Have a look at [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) or the relevant section of the [GNU Coreutils manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/date-invocation.html) for more details about the available formats.

Unfortunately, this only works with the GNU version of `date`.  The [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html) does not specify the `--date` option.

Comment: MJD format ist not month-year-day. Its an astronomically used non-POSIX "epoch" value that is given in days. you might look it up on the web for the details.